# Finding mode in np.array 1d and get the first one

Tags: python, numpy

I want to find the mode and get the first one for numpyarray

for example

`[1,2,2,3,3,4]` there are two mode(most frequently appears) `2`,`3`

However , in this case I want to get the most left one `2`

There are some examples to get mode by `numpy` or `scipy` or `staticts`

My array is numpy, so if I can do with only numpy, it is simple...

However how can I make this??

Comment: `sorted(Counter(arr).items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[-2:]` will give top 2 `(element, frequency)`. Don;t forget to `from collections import Counter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you had a look at `collections.Counter`?

```
import numpy as np
import collections

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3])
c = collections.Counter(x)
largest_num, count = c.most_common(1)[0]
```

The documentation of `Counter.most_common` [states](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common):

> Elements with equal counts are ordered in the order first encountered

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only numpy, you could try this, based on the scipy mode [implementation](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.6.0/scipy/stats/stats.py#L485-L575)

```
a = np.array([1,2,2,3,3,4])

# Unique values 
scores = set(np.ravel(a))

# Retrieve keys, counts
keys, counts = zip(*[(score, np.sum((a == score))) for score in scores])

# Maximum key
keys[np.argmax(counts)]
>>> 2
```

where the `argmax` function [states](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html)

> "In case of multiple occurrences of the maximum values, the indices corresponding to the first occurrence are returned."